# Unexpected Symbol '=' in class, struct or interface declaration

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine

Please forgive and correct my bad mistakes in my code, I am a somewhat noob.

I was casually working on a script lately to control a car with the hinge motor, I thought, why don't I use the unity documentation. I went and transferred the code to my project:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
void Start() {
    HingeJoint hinge = GetComponent<HingeJoint>();
    JointMotor motor = hinge.motor;
    motor.force = 100;
    motor.targetVelocity = 90;
    motor.freeSpin = false;
    hinge.motor = motor;
    hinge.useMotor = true;
    }
}
```

I attempted to change the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WHEELSPIN : MonoBehaviour {

    HingeJoint hinge = GetComponent<HingeJoint>();
    private JointMotor motor = hinge.motor;
    hinge.useMotor = true;
    hinge.motor = float motorz;
    motorz.freeSpin = true;


    private void Update()
     {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical"))
        {
            motorz.force = 1000;
            motorz.targetVelocity = 900;
        }
    }
}
```

I was advised previously to not use the same variable as the object, hence why it is called motorz. I was also told not to declare variables in the start function or else I can't use it in the other functions, and I also changed that but NOW I get an error message saying that the '=' symbol is unexpected. How can I fix this?

Edit: forgot to mention that this script is going into the back wheels of the car, not the actual car object.

Comment: You cannot use a function outside a function. In the `WHEELSPIN` script, move `hinge = GetComponent<HingeJoint>();` into a function. Do the-same for `motor = hinge.motor;` and the code below it except for the code in the `Update` function.

Comment: `hinge.motor = float motorz;` is not valid syntax.

Comment: @Dennis_E It partly works, but I need to know how it is not valid. Does removing float help? Also, now I am getting an error saying motorz does not exist.

Comment: @DavZRazorbladesDJDavZ I have no idea what you're trying to do so I can't answer that. But the float is not allowed to be at that `spot`. And as Programmer has said, you cannot call that code outside of a method.

Comment: @Dennis_E O What I am trying to do is get the back wheels of a car to move. They are attached using a hinge. I understand I cant call that code outside of a function, but when I move that script, as programmer said, it says motorz does not exist in the current context.

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `hinge.motor = float motorz;` Because it looks like gibberish.

Comment: Declare your variables outside the function if you want them to be global to the class. Otherwise declare them inside the function. Then assign them inside the function.

Comment: @Dennis_E I removed the float, just realised what I did.

Answer (score 2):

In your WheelSpin class, you are assigning your hinge in the class's constructor. However, monobehaviours are constructed arbitrarily by the Unity engine (when Unity serializes the class instance, which may happen for lots of reasons). Instead the Start() and Awake() callbacks should be used instead for initialising variables.

Comment: I don't think the code means that it is assigning hinge in class's constructor. It does not compile at all! So it has nothing to do with Unity engine. Moreover, public parameterless constructor is actually valid (that is, it does not break things) for MonoBehaviours. I suspect that Unity deserializes objects with `Activator.CreatInstance()` so you should not define any constructor other than a public parameterless one.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this because I don't have the libraries you're using, but this should help....

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WHEELSPIN : MonoBehaviour 
{

    HingeJoint hinge;
    JointMotor motorz;

    private void Awake()
    {
        hinge = GetComponent<HingeJoint>();
        motorz = hinge.motor;
        hinge.useMotor = true;
        motorz.freeSpin = true;
    }

    private void Update() 
    {       
        if (Input.GetAxis("Vertical") > 0f) 
        {
            motorz.force = 1000;
            motorz.targetVelocity = 900;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should this help?

Comment: Atleast this is buildable and seems to make sense

Comment: Thanks for the script, it has no bugs, but it doesn't rotate the wheels. Il try to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are confused by the ***field initializers***. But before explaining what a field initializer is, I should probably start by how to correctly define a *class*.

A class in c# is like a contract or mold in the real world. After you defined a class, you can use it to create *instances* (like using a mold to cast objects in the real world). Every instance of the same class follows the behaviour defined in the class. It has certain *fields* to store data and *methods* to be operated with.

Here is how a class would usually be defined:

```
// Double slashes starts a one-line comment
// Comments will be **ignored** when the program is running
// So comments are actually memos for programmers
// Here the class is named as "Creature"
class Creature
{
    // Here you can put some fields that will be used to store data
    int _heathPoint;

    // _healthPoint = 10; // Not permitted because this is not a field declaration

    // Here you can define methods that can be operated with
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // A method can be empty, just do nothing.
    }
}
```

You may see that in this class I defined a field `_healthPoint` and a method `DoSomething` and nothing else. In fact, in the "scope" of the class (the area enclosed by the first level of curvy braces after the `class` keyword), **only** field and method declarations are permitted (Well, not totally, you can add nested classes actually. But that is beyond the scope of this Q&A).

If you create a new instance of class `Creature`, this instance will have an integer field `_heathPoint` and a method `DoSomething`. But what will the value of its field be? In the above definition, it does not have any word about how the initial value will be, so `_healthPoint` will be set to its *default* value: it means `0` for `int` data.

For most of the times, such field value defaults are not what we want. In our case, it is not making any sense to have a `Creature` instance having initial `_healthPoint` set to `0`. Let's say we would like it to have initial `_healthPoint` to be `100`. Here is how we can do it:

```
class Creature
{
    int _heathPoint;

    // Below is something new.
    // Please note that although it looks like an ordinary method like DoSomething(),
    // it lacks the return type and has the same name as the class name
    // Such a method is called **constructor**
    public Creature()
    {
        _healthPoint = 100;
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

Here you can see we added a new method, which has the same name as its hosting class. Such method is called **constructor**. As its name suggests, constructors are called automatically when you attempt to construct a instance of a class.
**However**, this does not means that constructors create instances, they are actually used to **initialize** instances. When the constructor is called, the instance has already been created. But the details are beyond the scope here.
All you need to know is that here the constructor of `Creature` initialize the value of `_healthPoint` to `100` whenever a new instance of `Creature` is created.
However, what if we have a hundred field in a class that needs to be initialized? It would be tedious and error prone to initialize them one by one in the constructor.
So the *field initializers* come to rescue. Other than initializing fields explicitly in the constructors, one can use field initializers to set initial value to fields **in place where they are declared**. Here is how it looks like in our example:

```
class Creature
{
    // Here the = 100 part is the field initializer
    int _heathPoint = 100;
    // Each field can only have one initializer
    // So the line below is wrong and will not compile
    // _healthPoint = 30; // wrong because _heathPoint has been declared above

    public Creature()
    {
        // Do not need to do anything because the field initializer does what we want
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

Here you may see the field declaration `int _healthPoint;` becomes `int _healthPoint = 100;`. What it means is that we define all instances of the class `Creature` will have a field named `_healthPoint`, and we want its value to be initialized to `100`.
More interestingly, you can put anything after the assignment operator `=` as long as it evaluates to the type of the declaring field (`int` in our case).
So `int _healthPoint = 100 + 20;` is valid and so is `int _healthPoint = Int.Parse("100");`. (You can try it out!)

So back to your original code, what I see is that you seem to try to initialize your fields (especially `hinge`). I hope from the explanation above you now understand that `hinge.useMotor = true;` is invalid because it is not a field declaration nor a part of a field initializer.

Okay, then how do we initialize `hinge` if we really wanted to? Remember that a field initializer can be anything that evaluates to the field type? This means that we can do our initialization in a method, and make the field initializer call the method, such as:

```
class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    HingeJoint hinge = InitializeHinge();

    private HingeJoint InitializeHinge()
    {
        // Note that the line below compiles but may not run or will report runtime error
        // I am not sure if you can call GetComponent() in field initializer
        HingeJoint returnValue = GetComponent<HingeJoint>();
        returnValue.useMotor = true;
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

In this way, once an instance of the `ExampleClass` is created, its field `hinge` will be initialized to be the `HingeJoint` returned by `GetComponent<HingeJoint>()` and get its `useMotor` field set to `true`.

Comment: Oh, now I get it! Could I initialise hinge in void start? Or do I have to create a custom one like private HingeJoint InitialiseHinge?

Comment: Of course you can initialize hinge in `Start` because Unity guarantees that `Start` of any class derived `MonoBehaviour` getting called once before any `Update` has been called. However, you probably need to ensure that all your initialization is completed before if you access this object (a instance of this class) from other classes, such as a steering wheel may change the direction of this wheel.

Comment: Or as other answers suggests, you can also initialize in `Awake`. You may check out the differences between them [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/awake-and-start).

Initialization/finalization in Unity (specifically for `MonoBehaviour`s) can have many problems due to execution order. But IMHO you could just ignore those problems at your current stage, implement any functionalities  you want, and make life easier.